# processingjs set screen dimensions before loading sketch

Tags: javascript, processing

I made an application on processing which requires these information in order to make correct measurements;

- horizontalScreenResolution
- verticalScreenResolution
- screenWidth
- screenHight

I would like to use processingjs and include my sketch in web page. I already done that. However, this application gives correct results for particular screen. In order to solve this problem I want to create a form using html and java-script. User will enter its monitor parameters and whenever he clicks on start button sketch will be loaded according to given parameters and program will give correct results for every screen. However, is it possible to set this parameters before processinjs loads sketch to web page? Normally, it is possible to reach projessing parameters from javascript vice versa  using processingjs. 
I don't know how to do achieve this task.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I would use `displayWidth` and `displayHeight` instead, these were added in Processing 2.0 (They replaced `screen.width` and `screen.height`). These are int values that tell you the size of the screen. So instead of asking every single person what their monitor parameters are. Just use these variables, should make your life much simpler I hope.

Comment: Dear Lain;
this variables gives the screen resolution not the screen with and height. I need physical dimensions of screen in cm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
void setup(){

    size(desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
}
```

to change the width and height of the canvas in pixels.